# I need a circular doubly linked list of type Person and i keep getting errors and i don't understand why

Tags: c++

class person - it has a constructor/ destructor

```
    class Personne{

public:
    string nom;
    int age;
    string gender;
    int birthyear;

Personne(string nom,int age,string gender,int birthyear){
    this->nom=nom;
    this->age=age;
    this->gender=gender;
    this->birthyear=birthyear;

}

~Personne();

};
```

class list - is a double linked list, and i tried to make it circular
i have an error at struct Node - no matching function for call to "personne::personne()"

and also at - paux->info = x;
use of deleted function 'node::node()"
i don t know what is wrong

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
struct Node
{ 
    T info;
    Node <T> *next; 
    Node <T> *prev; 
};

template <typename T>
class CircularList
{
    public:
        Node <T> *pfirst; 
        Node <T> *plast; 

    void addFirst(T x)
    {
        

        Node<T> *paux = new Node<T>;

        paux->info = x; 
        paux->prev = plast;
        paux->next = pfirst;

        if (pfirst != NULL)
            pfirst->prev = paux;

        pfirst = paux; au

        if (plast==NULL)
            plast=pfirst;
    }

    void addLast(T x)
    {
       

        Node<T> *paux = new Node <T>;
        paux->info = x;
        paux->prev = plast;
        paux->next = pfirst;

        if (plast != NULL)
            plast->next = paux;

        plast = paux;

        if (pfirst == NULL)
            pfirst = plast;
    }

    T getInfo (Node<T>* p)
    {
        
        return p->info;
    }

    void removeFirst()
    {
        
        Node<T>* paux;

        if (pfirst != NULL)
        {
            paux = pfirst->next;

            if (pfirst == plast)
                plast = NULL;

            delete pfirst; 

            pfirst = paux;  

            if (pfirst != NULL)
                pfirst->prev = plast;
        }
        else
            cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
    }

    void removeLast()
    {
        
        Node <T> *paux;

        if (plast != NULL)
        {
            paux = plast->prev;

            if (pfirst == plast)
                pfirst = NULL;

            delete plast; //efface avec delete

            plast = paux; //le noeud anterieur devient le nouveau "last"
            if (plast != NULL)
                plast->next = pfirst;
        }
        else
            cout<<"The list is empty"<<endl;
    }

    Node <T>* findFirstOccurrence(T x)
    {
        //cherche le premier noeud qui contient info x
        Node <T> *paux;

        paux = pfirst;

        while (paux != NULL)
        {
            if (paux->info == x)
                return paux;
            paux = paux->next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }


    Node <T>* findLastOccurrence(T x)
    { //cherche le dernier noeud qui contient info x
        Node <T> *paux;

        paux = plast;
        while (paux != NULL) {
            if (paux->info == x)
                return paux;
            paux = paux->prev;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    void removeFirstOccurrence(T x)
    {
        //efface le premier noeud qui contient info x
        Node <T> *px;

        px = findFirstOccurrence(x); //px va etre efface

        if (px != NULL)
        {//on doit les relier
            if (px->prev != NULL)
                px->prev->next = px->next;

            if (px->next != NULL)
                px->next->prev = px->prev;

            if (px->prev == NULL) // if px == pfirst
                pfirst = px->next;

            if (px->next == NULL) // if px == plast
                plast = px->prev;

            delete px; //maintenant on peux l'effacer
        }
    }

    void removeLastOccurrence(T x)
    {
       // efface le dernier noeud qui contient info x
        Node <T> *px;

        px = findLastOccurrence(x);

        if (px != NULL)
        {
            if (px->prev != NULL)
                px->prev->next = px->next;

            if (px->next != NULL)
                px->next->prev = px->prev;

            if (px->prev == NULL) // if px == pfirst
                pfirst = px->next;

            if (px->next == NULL) // if px == plast
                plast = px->prev;

            delete px;
        }
    }


    int isEmpty()
    { //verifie si la liste est vide
        return (pfirst == NULL);
    }

    CircularList()
    { //constructeur
        pfirst = plast = NULL;
    }



};
```

main - where i try to add the objects

```
    CircularList<Personne> listp;

    cout<<"ecrivez le details sur les personnes"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<P;i++)
    {
        string nom;
        cout<<i+1<<" personne: "<<endl;
        cout<<"-le nom: ";
        cin>>nom;
        int age;
        cout<<"-l'age";
        cin>>age;
        string gender;
        cout<<"-gender: ";
        cin>>gender;
        int year;
        cout<<"-birthyear: ";
        cin>>year;
        Personne p(nom,age,gender,year);
        listp.addLast(penter code here);
    }
```

Comment: `Personne` has no default constructor, so `Node<T>` doesn't either. It contains a `T`.

Comment: "no matching function for call to personne::personne()" Could the error message be any more explicit? Make a default constructor.

Comment: and for undefined reference to 'Personne>::Personne()' what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node<Personne>` contains a `Personne`, and since you're not initializing it yourself it would need a default constructor.
You *could* require that all instantiation types be default-constructible, but since you're always going to set `info` to something, add constructors to `Node<T>` instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{ 
    Node(const T& data) : info(data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
    Node(const T& data, Node<T>* p, Node<T>* n) : info(data), next(n), prev(p) {}
    T info;
    Node <T> *next; 
    Node <T> *prev; 
};
```

and then

```
void addFirst(T x)
{
    Node<T> *paux = new Node<T>(x, plast, pfirst);
    if (pfirst != NULL)
        pfirst->prev = paux;
    pfirst = paux;

    if (plast==NULL)
        plast=pfirst;
}
```